# When should you use ng-content and component template with inputs and whats the difference?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

What's the difference between using ng-content and using the `childcomponent` selector inside the parent?

I can't really figure out when and why one or the other.

Examples:

```
//Parent
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: '<app-child [text]="'lorem ipsum'"></app-child>',
})

//Child
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<p>{{text}}</p>',
})
// ... component class with "@Input() text"
```

versus

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: '<app-child>
                   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
               </app-child>',
})

//Child
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
```

Comment: The content projection allow us use the component writing the .html in the parent. Imagine you want to "decorate" an input, instead of make a component with severals `@Inputs` for type, placeholder, enabled, width, height, maxlength... you can use content projection (when you use the component include in the .html of the parent the input), or if you has a table and want tcreate a carousel and want inside can be images or text or cards or..., it's better implemented the logic in component (move the items, add the arrows, create a thumbails...) but allow define the "items" in parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your example, the content projection is a bit different from `Input`.

With the `ng-content` you are projecting your component from parent to child, and you can't work with that data on your child component.

Instead, with `Input` the data is provided by the parent, but you can modify it in order to fit your UI and you **should** add a signature to the data that are incoming and work on it:

```
@Input() yourData: YourInterface | YourType
```

And with content projection (`ng-content`) this is not possible, because you can just draw the element from above and the child **doesn't know** what it is. It's logic will be: draw what it receives, no matter what.

Comment: So it's just a separation of code?
I could still just have all the logic in the parent component.

Comment: Yes, you can have all the logic in the parent, but in this way, you are going to duplicate the code if the component has to do the same logic every time instead passing a defined property to your child component

Comment: "you can't work with that data on your child component", really not: you can access to the "inner" using `@ContentChild` or `@ContentChildren` -generally using "directives"-